# How can I get a count from this inline view?

Tags: sql, pervasive, derived-table

I'm accessing an Actian Pervasive DB using PSQL Control Center (v12) and am trying to get a count from a very simple inline view, using the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
SELECT t3.customerid,
       t3.logchannels,
       COUNT(*)
  FROM table1 t1,
       table2 t2,
       table3 t3
 WHERE t2.id = t1.id
   AND t3.customerid = t1.customerid
GROUP BY t3.customerid,
         t3.logchannels
HAVING COUNT(*) <> t3.logchannels
)
```

The inner query runs fine, but as soon as it's turned into an inline view and the outer `SELECT` is added, it returns a syntax error. There's no additional information in the error message at all, it simply says "Syntax Error" and then reproduces the query.

I then tried to create  a table using the above query instead, thinking I could then just get a count from that, however this query also returns a syntax error:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_inv_channels AS
SELECT cm.customerid,
cm.logchannels,
COUNT(*)
FROM mmmastst mm,
rmmastst rm,
cmmastst cm
WHERE rm.recorderid = mm.recorderid
AND cm.customerid = mm.customerid
GROUP BY cm.customerid,
cm.logchannels
HAVING COUNT(*) <> cm.logchannels
```

As you can probably tell, I've never used Actian Pervasive before (I come from an Oracle background) and despite much Googling I still don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can anybody help? Presumably it's something really silly!

Comment: "*Actian Pervasive DB*" is a **completely** different database product than PostgreSQL. And "PSQL Control Center" refers to "Pervasive PSQL Control Center" and has nothing to do with PostgreSQL's command line client named `psql`

Comment: Try giving that inline view an alias by adding `as t` after the final closing `)` - at least that's what many DBMS products require (Oracle does not require the alias).

Comment: Adding the alias worked! Thanks. And apologies for the confusion re: PostgreSQL. When I Google 'PSQL', all of the results returned refer to PostgreSQL and the similarity in client names adds to the confusion.
For future reference, what "flavour" of SQL am I using here, to interrogate this Pervasive database? Is it still PSQL? If so, much of what I found on Google re: syntax is also incorrect.

Comment: The DOCS for Pervasive 12 are here: https://docs.actian.com/psql/PSQLv12/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm#href=welcome/libwelcome.html